# Code pasting incorrectly into IDLE shell on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-idle

I was trying to copy and paste some code into my Python shell, but when more than a single line in pasted in, I get the error: `SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement`.

I have a computer running Windows 10. I have always been annoyed that I couldn't copy-paste code and run it.

Is there any way to get all the code to separate into different statements? As if I had written it line-by-line / copy-pasted each line separately?

Here's what's happening:

[image: screenshot showing error]

Comment: The Shell in IDLE isn't the "real" Python console you get by just running `python` at the command prompt. This is so it can add features the latter doesn't have like auto-help and auto-completion. You _can_ paste multiple statements in the real Python shell without getting the error, so you could use it instead, or use one of the workarounds suggested to the linked duplicate question. There are other (free) interactive shells like [IPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython) which many folks like better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The '>>> ' prompt in IDLE means "Enter one statement".  Whenever you hit  at the end of entered code, whether keyed or pasted, IDLE assumes that you have done just that and tries to compile your code as a single statement by calling `compile` with `mode='single'`.  I have thought about how to handle multi-statement pastes, but it is a non-trivial problem.

For the present, paste into an editor window, and run from there.  I have a scratch file that I use for this purpose.  I use it often enough that I usually can load it from File => Recent Files, hit ^A (select all), ^V (paste, on Windows), and F5.

Answer (score 1):

The problem stems from the way that the IDLE shell handles copy/paste of multiple lines. Namely, it takes the end of each line as the user hitting the `enter` key which causes problems when copying code. The problem can be solved by starting a new file in IDLE, copy pasting the code into the new window, saving it as a `.py` file and then running the file from cmd with `python 'path\to\file'`.

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: I tried that and got `Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'python' is not defined`

Comment: Do you mind sending a screenshot of the cmd and posting your code so I can see the issue?

Comment: Edited to include the ss. I also tried it within the Python cmd, but to no avail.

Comment: In the screenshot you are pointing to the root python directory. The initial keyword `python` is called a PATH variable and it launches python for you. Instead, write `python path\to\file\file.py`.

Comment: Still getting the same error.

Comment: Daniel: It (now) doesn't look like the OP is using IDLE.

Comment: @martineau I can assure you that I am 100% using IDLE.

Comment: It seems like your PATH variables may not have been setup correctly if you keep getting a name error. Instead, copy/paste your code into an IDLE file using the process I outlined in my answer and then run the code using the Run module functionality found in the "run" drop-down menu in the IDLE file view.

Comment: @Daniel: It doesn't look like it the screenshot you added to in your question and you don't mention IDLE either.

Comment: @DanielWeber I just edited my question again with another screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Python is not added to the environment variables, and that's the first problem to solve. To do that, go to Control Panel\Environment Variables\System Variables and add the location to your python.exe file. For example, in my case I am using Anaconda, so I added this "C:\Users..\Anaconda3" to the environment variables. First, you need to know where is your python installed.

Then, open new command prompt and just write : python. If it works, then you see python version and other details. If not, then something wrong with the path setup.

After that, you can run the file that contains the multi lines, that you want to execute.

I hope it will help.